# Silverlight Grid Auto Size not working within canvas

Tags: silverlight, grid, canvas, autoresize

How do you make a grid width 100% inside a canvas? Here's some simple XAML but it doesn't work as expected.

```
<Canvas Background="MediumSlateBlue" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" >
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" MouseMove="MainPage_MouseMove" Background="Beige" >
        <TextBlock x:Name="lblDisplay" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128" Text="asdf" ></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

I don't understand why my grid doesn't take up as much room as it can get it's hands on! I've even tried adding a single row and column definition with a width of 100*, but still my grid will only take up as much space as the label it contains. The goal is to have a canvas, with a grid child and takes up 100% width and height. This is important because I need the silverlight to resize when the browser resizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I found a solution here

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/13415.aspx

I've adjusted my code to automatically resize my grid whenever the content is resized. This will allow me to position elements absolutly using Canvas.LeftProperty and maintain the position of horizontally/vertically aligned elements.

I considered using just a grid as my primary layout, however should the need arise to animate an object, margin cannot be animated. Additionally, setting the margin Left and Top during the mousemove event did not accurately position my element to the cursor position.

Answer (score 3):

Canvas lays out its content using absolute positioning. It's much more similar to the way Windows Forms worked in that all elements must have a top, left, width, and height specified.

You can achieve similar functionality by replacing Canvas with a Grid that has no rows/columns defined and use margins to place child elements.

Comment: Indeed, he could eliminate the Canvas altogether, as it already has a Grid inside of it.

Comment: Which is how I had everything to begin with. It was only when I went to start positioning elements with Canvas.LeftProperty is when I ran into this issue. I'm experimenting with margin at the moment and will see how it works out. I may resort to just setting the width/height when the browser is resized.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding Canvas for this scenario. It's primarily designed for situations where you don't want any layout. From your example it appears there's no need for the outer panel at all but using a single-cell Grid as a simple layout panel is very common and in fact is the default panel used by Blend and Visual Studio.

Comment: Great answer Josh, it saved me tons of headache!

Answer (score 0):

Also check to make sure that your form is actually stretching the Silverlight application.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="clientbin/MyApp.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40818.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
</form>
```